# Stuck with php function with boolean

Tags: php

In the following code, I'm trying to do as you'll see below.

```
<?php
$urlHead = 'a';

function heading($urlHead){
    switch($urlHead){
        case 'c':
        $tab = '1';
        break;

        case 'i':
        $tab = '2';
        break;

        case 'r':
        $tab = '3';
        break;

        case 'a':
        $tab = '4';
        break;

        default:
        return false;
    }
}


if (heading($urlHead)) {
    echo 'Success;
        echo $tab;
} else {
    echo 'Fail';

}
?>
```

It's got to return true, and also the`$tab` value from inside the function. But `$tab = 1` = false. This whole thing has me in knots. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this, basically, you need to return the $tab;

```
<?php
$urlHead = 'a';

function heading($urlHead)
{
    switch ($urlHead)
    {
        case 'c' :
            $tab = '1';
            break;

        case 'i' :
            $tab = '2';
            break;

        case 'r' :
            $tab = '3';
            break;

        case 'a' :
            $tab = '4';
            break;

        default :
            return false;
    }

    //return $tab
    return $tab;
}

$tab = heading ( $urlHead );

if ($tab)
{
    echo 'Success';
    echo $tab;
}
else
{
    echo 'Fail';
}
```

Comment: Set `$urlHead = a`; and it'll return false always.

Comment: you mean = 'a'  as the same code. I just run it, it outputs "Success4" for me.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant $`urlHead = c`

Comment: with $urlHead = 'c'(not just c) , it outputs "Success1"

Comment: Do you miss this line: $tab = heading ( $urlHead );

Comment: You're correct. It works fine. Is it possible to proceed without the line `$tab = heading ( $urlHead );` By doing just `if (heading($urlHead))`

Comment: Yep, if you don't need the return result, then you can just use if(heading ( $urlHead )){ echo 'Success'}

Comment: This brings in another problem. I have yet another function, just the same way, except that when `case 'c': $tab = 0`. And that will always return false :-). Should I post another question for that?

Comment: if(0) will be false, but you can use if(heading ( $urlHead ) !== false)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning the $tab variable.

New Code

```
function heading($urlHead){
  switch($urlHead){
    case 'c':
    $tab = '1';
    break;

    case 'i':
    $tab = '2';
    break;

    case 'r':
    $tab = '3';
    break;

    case 'a':
    $tab = '4';
    break;

    default:
    return false;
  }
  return $tab;
}
```

Comment: If you set `$urlHead = c` it'll always return false.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have return in case of 'a' in heading. Default return is null which interpreted as false
Also you have $tab in method and outside of it in different scopes